# How to manage work permit stress along with research work?

Tags: emotional-responses, international, visa

Since academia especially in postdoctoral contracts requires researchers to move around, I suppose being in academia in the long-term would make most people think about the work permit/visa situation with/without family.

How to keep up the quality of research while awaiting and managing work permit/visa applications for work? I am wrapping up my PhD now and writing manuscripts and leading the simulations for these research projects. I need to focus on my papers and take care of the preprints to the state that they are ready to be submitted to the journals.

My supervisor and department provide no support whatsoever in this situation, i.e., they provide the documents in time but do not provide any support to me to plan my employment in such a way that the transition in work permit is smooth.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? You are a person and you have legitimate concerns other than just research, and you need to find a way to balance those. How to do that depends on your needs and the possibilities in your situation. We don't know either.

Comment: OP: can you provide at least the continent in which you are located?

@MaartenBuis although I generally agree, "you need to find a way to balance [...]" it's like saying "you are a sailorman on the Titanic, the ship just hit an iceberg, you need to find a way to balance your duties with your physical and mental wellbeing". Not easy, and really not too much depending on the specific OP situation.

Comment: @EarlGrey the location is in northern Europe (EU).

Comment: @Wandering_Alice  I would go as far to say that it is fully responsibility of the State, your faculty cannot influence in the future visa process (they already contribute enough by showing they employed you in the past). Just fill in the necessary paperwork, do not visit questionable websites (where questionable can be either far-right pro-indigeneous sites or far-left)?) pro-immigration sites, it depends on the current government), avoid political activities and you are all set.
Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer or a pious man, there is no legal or moral value or binding in what I write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry: to have a safe visa renewal process, you need a long-term contract. No one in the academia will provide you a long term contract.

So don't stress out in the sense that "the academia" will never help you and you are just in need of luck.

As long as you have a PhD defended and you are a "doctor", and as long as your criminal record is short or null, and you have no visits to Iran (applies for the US), you can be reasonably sure you will get a visa.